# Iterate over three rows then do linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, loops, linear-regression

I want to iterate over three rows in only two columns, then in the function of iteration, I do linear regression in that three rows. So, iterate over three rows, do linear regression, iterate over three rows, do linear regression, so on.

I put the data input [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWSdd.png) . I want to iterate over three rows in column Year and Value then do linear regression, then iterate over three rows in column Year and Value then do linear regression, so on.

I already try this code but there is an error

```
year=data_['Year']
value=data_['Value']
i=0
count=0

for a,b in zip(year,value):
    print(a,b)
    count = count+1

    if count%3 == 0:

        x=np.array([[a]])
        y=np.array([[b]])

        reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
        x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2 ,random_state=3)
        reg.fit(x_train,y_train)

        y4=4*reg.coef_ + reg.intercept_
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.show()
        print(reg.coef_)
        print("R^2 : ",reg.score(x, y))
        print("Equation : 4 *", reg.coef_, "+", reg.intercept_)
        print("Y4 : ", y4)
        print("====")
```

I expect the output every three rows result a slope, coefficient, and equation.

Comment: 1) Report the error, don't just say that there is an error. 2) Why do you want to do linear regression with only 1 data point? An infinite number of lines pass over 1 point; so you need at least 2. Also, why try to do a train-test split with only 1 data point? 3) You need to look up the following: a) indexing with pandas, b) iterating with pandas, c) Other answers in S.O. before posting.

Comment: Right now, your code does nothing for every 2 iterations and tries to do a linear regression on a single x,y pair every third... You should at least replace `reg.fit(x,y)` by `reg.fit(x_train,y_train)`

Comment: @Energya there is an error "TypeError: Singleton array array(3) cannot be considered a valid collection."

Comment: @KostasMouratidis 1) an error ""TypeError: Singleton array array(3) cannot be considered a valid collection." 2) i want to do linear regression with x from Year column and y from Value column. so, i could predict Year 4 every different three rows. if this is what I want, does it really need train-test split

Comment: No, you do not need a train-test-split. Also, what you probably want is not to iterate over rows like you do, you need to iterate over pandas indices, perhaps doing something along the lines of: `x = years[idx-3:idx]` (pick rows `idx-3`, `idx-2`, and `idx-1`) and predict `y = values[idx]`, which will need for x to be reshaped (maybe like so: `x.values.reshape((1,-1))`) and similarly for y (`y.reshape((1,1))`). Even so, this is not optimal, and you probably want to do something else, like a rolling prediction with window 3. Maybe it would be better following a few tutorials on time series.

Comment: @KostasMouratidis how to define idx? yes, i would like to do something like rolling prediction window 3 with linear regression but i cant find the efficient way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do a simple linear regression per group of three years, try something like this:

```
# Hardcoded input data for clarity
#all_years = data_['Year'].values
#all_values = data_['Value'].values
all_years = np.array([1,2,3,
                      1,2,3,
                      1,2,3,
                      1,2,3,
                      1,2,3])
all_values = np.array([  6.262008,   5.795994,   5.082662,
                       285.433511, 260.436601, 238.713124,
                         2.596145,   2.508278,   2.67997, 
                        90.823952,  91.0962765, 93.821241,
                        19.677544,  18.464335,  18.035489])


w = 3  # window size
for i in range(len(all_years)//w):

    years = all_years[w*i : w*(i+1)].reshape(-1,1)
    values = all_values[w*i : w*(i+1)].reshape(-1,1)
    #print(years, values)

    reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(years, values)

    y=(w+1)*reg.coef_ + reg.intercept_
    plt.scatter(years, values)
    plt.show()
    print(reg.coef_)
    print("R^2 : ",reg.score(years, values))
    print("Equation : (w+1) *", reg.coef_, "+", reg.intercept_)
    print("Y4 : ", y)
    print("====")
```

In this case, the length will be `15`, so the for-loop will go through `i= 1, ..., 4`. Then I select the years and values you want using numpy's array slicing.

For example, for i=1, this will select `[3*(1-1) : 3*1]` = `[0 : 3]`, giving exactly the first three rows. To then make sure this works nicely with linear regression expecting a column vector, I reshape the array to consist of 1 column with `.reshape(-1, 1)`.

Then it's a matter of training and plotting as you want.

For a version that's nicer to read and avoids manual indexing issues, you may also want to look into the [`more-itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package. Specifically the [`chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) method is useful in this case to split the data into chunks of fixed length, 3 in this case:

```
from more_itertools import chunked

...

w = 3  # window size  
for years, values in zip(chunked(all_years, n=w), chunked(all_values, n=w)):

    years = years.reshape(-1,1)
    values = values.reshape(-1,1)
    #print(years, values)

    ...
```

Comment: i have tried using all_years = data_['Year'] & all_values = data_['Value'], but there is an error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'" because data_ actually has 552 rows.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that it's extracted as a Series instead of an array. Just add `.values` to the `data_['Year']` as I've updated in the answer.

Comment: sorry to ask, but why the last three rows don't appear in the result? There are 551 data, but it is only 548 in the output

Comment: @WindyAuliaR. indexing mistake: the range in the for loop was one too short. I've updated that in the answer and added a version that doesn't require manual indexing either